# Cassandra node hardware: 2 vs 4 of double specs?

Tags: database, cassandra, cluster-computing

according to what Ive read about cassandra, it has linear performance with nodes. Ive read that cassandra recommends a minimal of 8gb of ram, and a target of 32gb ram for production, but dont know if this specs are per node, or total.

The question is;

> Case A) 8x nodes of  8gb ram 4 cores - total 64gb ram and 32 cores
>
> Case B) 4x nodes of 16gb ram 6 cores - total 64gb ram and 24 cores

Both cases costs the same, but case A has 8 additional cores, but less ram per core... Anyone has benchmarked this scenario, or knows which solution performs better?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hardware for either case appears to be low on RAM.  Generally, RAM specifications are per node - not per data center or per cluster.

A more general answer:

The performance of your specific application will impact the number of nodes required; and the hardware requirements based on bottlenecking (memory, CPU, I/O), so its nearly impossible to answer your question.

However, I would note there is an advantage to having 8 nodes vs 4 nodes when it comes to availability - something you did not mention.  In general, more smaller nodes is a good way to go with Cassandra due to partitioning and availability.

Comment: more smaller nodes also means things like replacements, bootstrapping etc is faster but you dont want to go very small. memory is most likely going to be your bottleneck and 8gb ram systems is not enough to run Cassandra well.

Comment: Which is the minimal amount of ram you recommend for each node?
Is it faster to have a machine with 64gb ram instead of two 32gb ?

Comment: 16 GB absolutely minimum. I had very bad experience with 8GB nodes. Always crashing no matter what memory configuration you had.